# Multi-thread function with mutable type argument

Tags: python, multithreading, mutable

```
import threading, time
class A():
    def __init__(self,a ):
        self.a = a

    def run(self):
        print(self.a)

if __name__=='__main__':
    index = [0]
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        index[0] = i
        thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=A(index).run))
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

This piece of code doesn't show the correct result with [0] - [9] sequence but all results are [9]. However, if change it to `thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=A(tuple(index)).run))`
or start directly rather than start it in another loop, or put index definition inside the loop the result is OK.
Here's another two correct version:

```
import threading, time
class A():
    def __init__(self,a ):
        self.a = a

    def run(self):
        print(self.a)

if __name__=='__main__':
    index = [0]
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        index[0] = i
        thread = threading.Thread(target=A(index).run)
        thread_list.append(thread_list)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

```
import threading, time
class A():
    def __init__(self,a ):
        self.a = a

    def run(self):
        print(self.a)

if __name__=='__main__':

    thread_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        index = [0]
        index[0] = i
        thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=A(index).run))
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

Somebody could explain the mechanism behind how Python initialize a Thread object and call start() method. Why is's always the last one when a mutable variable pass into function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your first snippet of code does what it does is because you're passing a mutable object (the list named `index`) when creating each of the class `A` instances, so when they print its value they all display whatever is currently in it—which will be the last thing was that was assigned to `index[0]` just before the `Thread` instance itself is created in the following line.

So a workaround would be to avoid passing the function a mutable object. The change indicated below is a trivial way of doing that in this case:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def run(self):
        print(self.a)

if __name__=='__main__':
    index = [0]
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        index[0] = i
#       thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=A(index).run))
        thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=A(index[0]).run()))
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one more question. When initialize object A by threading.Thread(target=A(index).run), instance of A is not fix like something deep copy or return value it's behavior more like list.append()?

Comment: When you pass a mutable objects in Python, it effectively passes a reference to the object not a copy of it. That reference is then assigned to the named argument of the function or method called. If you want a copy passed you must make it yourself. The easiest way in your code would be to use `threading.Thread(target=A(index[:]).run)`—the added `[:]` will create a copy of the entire list(not just the first element as in my answer) at **that moment**, and pass that copy as the argument's value.